# Linking a lib library in C using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker

I added to Visual studio Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies the `x.lib` file. My build was successful but program didnt start because after start it wrotes: `The program cant start because of x.dll is missing from your computer.` Why is it looking for `x.dll` and not `x.lib`?

Answer (score 0):

*For dynamic linking*:

`x.lib` is used for compiling, which contains the linking information of library functions. When compiling, compiler just check whether these functions exist. To understand it simply, compiling will give the way to locating these functions in `dll` files.
While `x.dll` is dynamic link library which contains the implementations (maybe not that accurate) of these functions. If you didn't set `dll` right, the program cannot execute the corresponding functions. **`dll` is the actually executable file, not `lib`**.

Comment: But your `x.lib` is a shim for `x.dll`, for you to skip the opening of the library and getting the pointer of each function and call these function, `x.lib` is a static library linked into your program

Comment: @dvhh I think there are two kinds of `lib`. One kind contains `dll` file information and the entry to api functions, the other kind contains function code itself and add the code to the program directly when compiling (like you said, static link library).

Comment: I was answering to @Мартин Бее, which was probably the one down voting you (unfortunately he deleted his comment, but apparently left the down vote )